# High frequency DOM mutations

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout

I've built a simple chronometer but I want it to be as *fast* and *accurate* as possible. In other words, I want the best refresh rate while keeping its precision and by precision I mean the digits for the seconds should change every 1000 ms, the minutes should change every 60 seconds, etc.

The [chronometer](https://gist.github.com/DrunkenPoney/fa671a68c5e9862cd3382026739f385f) itself was pretty easy to make but I get weird behaviours when I try to make it fast.

At first, the chronometer was just stuck at 00:00 and it would not even change. But I quickly realized it was because I wasn't giving the browser any time to render the element between every execution of the function that updates and formats the time. So I tried to make it so every next update is made after a 0 ms timeout. This way, I thought it would put the execution of the next update at the end of the execution stack so the browser would have rendered the element before the next update function is executed.

The timeout fixed my issue but only partially. The chronometer seemed to be working fine until I realized that a second was skipped every so often.

I tried adding a small delay of like 5 ms to the timeout but seconds were still skipped though the delay between every skipped seconds was larger. I tried to play with the delay of the timeout but seconds are still skipped even with a delay of over 50 ms. I even tried to use the [`queueMicrotask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask) function and combine it with the timeout but it didn't help.

At this point, I tried to find another solution but I couldn't find anything. I don't understand why this is happening so I would really appreciate if anyone could explain me what's going on and how I can fix this.

***Note:** the delay between each skipped seconds is not constant and for some reason, seconds are skipped more often after 1 minute.*

## The chronometer

```js
const START_TIME = Date.now();

function formatTime(ms) {
  ms = Math.round(ms * 1);
  let secs = Math.trunc(ms / 1e3);
  ms = (ms / 1e3 - secs) * 1e3;

  let mins = Math.trunc(secs / 60);
  secs = (secs / 60 - mins) * 60;

  let hours = Math.trunc(mins / 60);
  mins = (mins / 60 - hours) * 60;

  hours = String(Math.trunc(hours));
  mins = String(Math.trunc(mins));
  secs = String(Math.trunc(secs));
  ms = String(Math.trunc(ms));

  const pad = (t, i = 2) => t.padStart(i, "0");
  return `${pad(hours)}:${pad(mins)}:${pad(secs)},${pad(ms, 3)}`;
}

(() => {
  const el = document.querySelector('.time');

  const update = () => {
    el.innerText = formatTime(Date.now() - START_TIME);
    setTimeout(update);
  }
  update();
})();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@300&display=swap");
body {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #35E;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(4vw + 4vh + 10vmin);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="time"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Update:**
I tried with `requestAnimationFrame` and I still get the same result.

Comment: Hi interesting, perhaps it needs to be flushed or refreshed with setTimeout or setInterval

Comment: settimeout is not accurate.... you can play with requestAnimationFrame, but that is also not going to be the miracle solution.

Comment: You should take a look at [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Smells like it's Math.trunc...

Comment: I'm going to agree with all the posters recommending [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).  You might also consider looking at the [`<canvas> API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)  as an alternative to the DOM; it might be better suited for your requirements.

Comment: I just tried with `requestAnimationFrame` and seconds are still skipped.

Comment: Re @Adam's comment, maybe where you do `(secs / 60 - mins) * 60`, instead do `(secs - mins * 60)`.  This eliminates a division operation, which is prone to small accuracy issues.  Of course, make this change in all places where this pattern exists...

Comment: @JonTrent You found it! I never thought it could be this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Adam found it!  Glad to hear your issue is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was bad math - you were accumulating error. I didn't accumulate any error below because I always operated on the ms.

```js
const START_TIME = Date.now();

function formatTime(diff) {
  // ms are always the last three digits
  const ms = ((diff / 1000 - Math.trunc(diff / 1000)) * 1000)
    .toFixed(0)
    .padStart(3, 0);

  // seconds are always the integer part of the diff when divided by 1000 - mod 60 here the number "wraps" when it gets to 60
  const seconds = (Math.trunc(diff / 1000) % 60).toFixed(0).padStart(2, 0);
  // minutes are always the integer part of the diff when divided by 1000*60 - mod 60 again
  const minutes = (Math.trunc(diff / (1000 * 60)) % 60)
    .toFixed(0)
    .padStart(2, 0);
 
  // hours are the integer part of the diff when divided by 1000*60*60
  const hours = Math.trunc(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60))
    .toFixed(0)
    .padStart(2, 0);
  return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}:${ms}`;
}

(() => {
  const el = document.querySelector('.time');

  const update = () => {
    el.innerText = formatTime(Date.now() - START_TIME);
    setTimeout(update);
  }
  update();
})();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@300&display=swap");
body {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #35E;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(4vw + 4vh + 10vmin);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="time"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get a better output using `performance.now()` and `requestAnimationFrame`

```js
const START_TIME = performance.now();

function formatTime(ms) {
  ms = Math.round(ms * 1);
  let secs = Math.trunc(ms / 1e3);
  ms = (ms / 1e3 - secs) * 1e3;

  let mins = Math.trunc(secs / 60);
  secs = (secs / 60 - mins) * 60;

  let hours = Math.trunc(mins / 60);
  mins = (mins / 60 - hours) * 60;

  hours = String(Math.trunc(hours));
  mins = String(Math.trunc(mins));
  secs = String(Math.trunc(secs));
  ms = String(Math.trunc(ms));

  const pad = (t, i = 2) => t.padStart(i, "0");
  return `${pad(hours)}:${pad(mins)}:${pad(secs)},${pad(ms, 3)}`;
}

(() => {
  const el = document.querySelector('.time');

  const update = () => {
    el.innerText = formatTime(performance.now() - START_TIME);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }
  update();
})();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@300&display=swap");
body {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #35E;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(4vw + 4vh + 10vmin);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="time"></div>
</div>
```

I personally would do the time calc like this

```js
const START_TIME = performance.now();

function formatTime(duration) {
  let milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000));
  let seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60);
  let minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
  let hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  milliseconds = (milliseconds < 10) ? "00" + milliseconds : milliseconds < 100 ? "0" + milliseconds : milliseconds;

  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "," + milliseconds;
}

(() => {
  const el = document.querySelector('.time');

  const update = () => {
    el.textContent = formatTime(performance.now() - START_TIME);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }
  update();
})();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@300&display=swap");
body {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #35E;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(4vw + 4vh + 10vmin);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="time"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't even need to call `performance.now` - just use the parameter of the raf callback.